# laravel products auction timer displayed only for last product

Tags: javascript, laravel, foreach, timer, laravel-blade

i work on a handicrafts auction website, so there is a special auction countdown (javascript timer) for each product, the timer work well for each product when i display the product details page

but when using foreach; it doesn't display except for the last product; and in the place of first product timer!!

you can check the result and the auction finish of each product
[image]

[image]
here is my blade code

```js
@extends('layouts.main_layout')
@section('content')
<div class="RecentAuction">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="RecentAuction-content">
        <h2 class="p-2">Recent Auctions</h2>
        <div class="row">
           @foreach($products as $product)
            <div class="col-3 col-3 mb-4 mt-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div id="countdown" class="timer text-center">
                        {{-- timer here --}}
                    </div>
                    <a href="{{route('product.details', $product->id) }}">
                        <img src="{{asset('/HandicraftsAuction/image/wool.jpg')}}" class="card-img-top">
                    </a>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="text-center">{{$product->title}}</h5>
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                            <span>MaxBid: {{$product->orderNowPrice}}$</span>
                        </div>
                        {{-- complement here --}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
           @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
@section('script')
<script>
    var seconds = {!! json_encode($product->remainingTime(), JSON_HEX_TAG) !!};
    function timer() {
        var days        = Math.floor(seconds/24/60/60);
        var hoursLeft   = Math.floor((seconds) - (days*86400));
        var hours       = Math.floor(hoursLeft/3600);
        var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours*3600));
        var minutes     = Math.floor(minutesLeft/60);
        var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
        function pad(n) {
            return (n < 10 ? "0" + n : n);
        }
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = pad(days) + ":" + pad(hours) + ":" 
            + pad(minutes) + ":" + pad(remainingSeconds);
        if (seconds == 0) {
            clearInterval(countdownTimer);
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Expired";
            location.reload();
        } else {
            seconds--;
        }
    }
    var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()', 1000);
</script>
@endsection
```

i think the problem is in passing laravel to javascript as js can't manipulate dynamic div content counter for each product using #id. however, using class instead doesn't make sense also!.

Comment: You are accessing `$product` outside the `foreach` loop

Comment: No the accessing is inside for each

Comment: is this `var seconds = {!! json_encode($product->remainingTime(), JSON_HEX_TAG) !!};` inside the `foreach` loop?

Comment: considering to be, as countdown id is inside! however i tried to move it inside foreach and it doesnt work

Comment: In JS you should only use unique ids https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page

Comment: thanks all, the solution exists here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31239280/showing-countdown-timer-on-each-foreach

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing countdown timer on each foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31239280/showing-countdown-timer-on-each-foreach)

Comment: yes, it solves my day, you can then customize the 5minuts to your timer